# runtime error: member access within misaligned address (leetcode 2nd question)

Tags: c, linked-list, runtime-error, memory-address

I have been trying to solve leetcode 2nd problem "Add two numbers" using "C" as the programming language. The problem question is as below.

> You are given two non-empty linked lists representing two non-negative integers. The digits are stored in reverse order, and each of their nodes contains a single digit. Add the two numbers and return the sum as a linked list.
>
> You may assume the two numbers do not contain any leading zero, except the number `0` itself.

The below example will give an idea about problem statement if you dont want to go to leetcode to check the question.`

```
Input: l1 = [2,4,3], l2 = [5,6,4]
Output: [7,0,8]
Explanation: 342 + 465 = 807.
```

Below is the struct definition given by leet code

```
struct ListNode {
    int val;
    struct ListNode *next;
};
```

below is the function given to us to return a linked list with the above output.

Below is my code

```
struct ListNode *addTwoNumbers(struct ListNode *l1, struct ListNode *l2) {
    int number1 = 0;
    int reverse1 = 0;
    int rotate = 1;
    int addnumbers;
    struct ListNode *final = (struct ListNode *)malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode));
    struct ListNode *current = final; 
    int split;

    while (l1 != NULL)
    {
        number1 = (l1->val * rotate) + number1; 
        l1 = l1->next;
        rotate = rotate * 10;
    }

    int number2 = 0;
    reverse1 = 0;
    rotate = 1;

    while (l2 != NULL)
    {
        number2 = (l2->val * rotate) + number2; 
        l2 = l2->next;
        rotate = rotate * 10;
    }
    addnumbers = number1 + number2;  

    while (addnumbers != 0)
    {
        split = addnumbers % 10;
        addnumbers = addnumbers / 10;
        if (final != NULL)
        {
            final->val = split; 
            printf("%d \n", final->val);
        }               
        if (addnumbers == 0)
        {
            final->next = NULL;
            break;
        }
        else
        {  
            final->next = malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode));  
        }  
        final = final->next;    
    }
    while (current != NULL)
    {
        printf(" The values are %d \n", current->val);
        current = current->next;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In the above code I didn't return the structure yet, but I can confirm that `8`, `0`, `7` are printing when the code is executed but a fourth address value is also getting printed out with a runtime error below

```
Line 58: Char 9: runtime error: member access within misaligned address 0xbebebebebebebebe for type 'struct ListNode', which requires 8 byte alignment [solution.c]
0xbebebebebebebebe: note: pointer points here
<memory cannot be printed>
```

I believe the last `while` loop should rotate only for 3 times but why is the fourth address getting printed out. Could you please point out the reason.

Comment: I suspect you're missing the null `next` pointer at the end of the input lists. So you're dereferencing an uninitialized pointer.

Comment: Sorry, but Stackoverflow is not really the best place to ask questions about specific coding puzzles from other web sites. Experienced Stackoverflow users generally have no interest in random coding puzzles. You can use the forums on those web sites to ask any questions about their coding puzzles, to people who spend a lot of time doing them. If you can [edit] your question and focus it on a specific C or C++ subject matter or topic, not related to any specific coding puzzle, then you're welcome to ask it.

Comment: Additionally, I expect that the test cases for that coding puzzle includes numbers with hundreds of digits, for which the coded attempt to convert each linked to a single `int` value will fali miserably, even after fixing all the bugs that make it crash. It is abundantly clear to me that the intended solution involves dynamic creation of a new linked list, representing the result of the addition, digit by digit. The shown code will have to be scrapped and rewritten in a completely different way, before it passes the coding puzzle's test cases.

Comment: `0xbebebebebebebebe` looks a lot like a sentinel value for uninitialized or out of bounds memory.

Comment: The digits to be added are in the right order for adding with carry, without doing any reversal. You only need to store the first list, and when you get to the second list it can be read and summed with first list and output digit by digit without any more storage. You don't need to create the entire numbers (which might be huge), and you don't need to reverse or rotate anything.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 problems in your code:

- you are limited by the range of type `int`, whereas the list representation can handle mych larger numbers.
- you modify both `final` and `current` so you might be returning the wrong pointer, causing the program to fail.
- in case both numbers are `0`, `addnumbers` is `0` and the `while` loop does not iterate at all, leaving the node pointed to by `final` uninitialized, potentially causing undefined behavior in the testing program. This may explain the runtime error.

Here is a modified version that can handle longer lists:

```
struct ListNode *addTwoNumbers(struct ListNode *l1, struct ListNode *l2) {
    struct ListNode *final = malloc(sizeof(*final));
    struct ListNode *current = final;
    int carry = 0;

    for (;;) {
        if (l1) {
            carry += l1->val;
            l1 = l1->next;
        }
        if (l2) {
            carry += l2->val;
            l2 = l2->next;
        }
        current->val = carry % 10;
        carry /= 10;
        if (carry || l1 || l2) {
            current->next = malloc(sizeof(*current));
            current = current->next;
        } else {
            current->next = NULL;
            return final;
        }
    }
}
```